# Can't build nginx w/ TCP module, error "target `build', needed by `default'"?

Tags: nginx

Following the instructions from the author: http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

Ran through these commands:

```
export NGINX_VERSION=1.0.12
curl -O http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz
git clone https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module.git
tar -xvzf nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz
cd nginx-$NGINX_VERSION
patch -p1 < ../nginx_tcp_proxy_module/tcp.patch
./configure --add-module=../nginx_tcp_proxy_module/
sudo make && make install
```

Everything went smoothly until the last command when I was derailed by `make: *** No rule to make target`build', needed by `default'.  Stop.`

Looks like the author put together instructions for 1.0.4 and I'm using 1.0.12, but I'm not sure if that changes the build process or if there's larger issues here. Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. It turns out I was missing pcre and didn't notice the error on the config step. Do you have that installed?

# apt-get update
# apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

Comment: interesting. honestly i abandoned this path when i started using a different framework and changed my SSL strategy. but i will give this a try anyways. add it as an answer to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

By moving my nginx-rtmp-module to the ./ folder I was able to configure properly. From there running  started the compiler.